# How to match parenthesis using a regular expression?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am using using boost libraries to parse a file. Its known that when you use a parenthesis it denotes a sub-expression in a regular expression. How would I declare a regular expression if my file contains parenthesis? I tried using `\(` with no luck. Could anyone tell me how I should declare a regular expression for the following format of file?

```
a:(1)
b:(2)
```

I'm able to do the parsing when the file content is

```
a:1
b:2
```

by declaring the regular expression as `boost::regex e("([a-z]):([0-9])");`
Can you tell me how I can also match if the values are in braces?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to use parentheses you need to escape them with a backslash. The issue is that you need to escape that backslash too (for the C++ compiler). Example:

```
std::string regexstring = "\\([a-z]\\):\\([0-9]\\)";
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This issue came up when I was transferring a regex pattern from C# to C++, I didn't realize the compiler treated them differently.  For people searching, this fixes the warning `C4129: '(': unrecognized character escape sequence`.